# pre load php code before running it

Tags: php, domdocument

Hello friends as they are?

I have the following question.

I have several files that contain php code, these files separately make a website, in fact every file generates different html code sections, as previously could do to capture the php code before it is executed.

I am reading each file and create a new file with all the code for each of them, but I wonder if there is any other way to capture php code directly into memory before running it.

I've tried using ob_ output buffer, but I returned the executed code (html).

The Control class is as follows:

```
class IndexCtrl extends CtrlAbs {
    public function show () {
        $template = new Template ( $this->template );
        $template->load ();
        $indexVst = new IndexVst ();
        $indexVst->load ();
        $phpJoined = JoinPhp::getInstance ();
        $phpJoined->setFile ();
        $phpJoined->joinFiles ();
        printf ( '%s', $phpJoined->load () );
        unlink ( $phpJoined->getArchivo () );
    }
}
```

Classes loaded the php code (template and view) are:

```
class IndexVst extends VistaAbs {
    public function load () {
        $phpJoined = JoinPhp::getInstance ();
        $phpJoined->addFile ( 'app/web/htmldom/vst/index.php' );
    }
}

class Template {
    public function load () {
        $phpJoined = JoinPhp::getInstance ();
        $phpJoined->addFile ( 'app/web/htmldom/templates/default.php' );
    }
}
```

Files containing the php code are:

default.php

```
use mod\api\htmldom\HtmlDom;
use mod\api\htmldom\common\Types;

$htmlDom = new HtmlDom();
```

index.php

```
$table0 = $htmlDom->table ();
$table0->border ( '1' );

$tr0 = $htmlDom->tr ();
$th0 = $htmlDom->th ();
$th0->scope ( 'col' );
$tr0->insert ( $th0 );

$tr1 = $htmlDom->tr ();
$td0 = $htmlDom->td ();
$strong0 = $htmlDom->strong ();
$strong0->insert ( 'Convert html to HTMLDOM' );
$td0->insert ( $strong0 );
$tr1->insert ( $td0 );

$table0->insert ( $tr0 );
$table0->insert ( $tr1 );

$htmlDom->body ( $table0 );
$htmlDom->showHtml ();
```

The latter two files contain the php code that generates the html code.

As I said, my question is, is there some other way to capture php code directly into memory before running it.

In advance greetings and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: what are you doing this for?

Comment: That's a very bizarre template system - it doesn't really abstract anything away.  Why not just output the HTML directly?

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. 

What I try to do with this system is to generate the html code in the same instant that a page is requested, is that this slows down the request for the same, but load testing of these so far are acceptable. What I'm trying to establish this system as an additional layer to reduce the possible injection of javascript and html code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is way to cache the php code in memory instead of reading it every time from disk. Read a little bit about PHP Opcode caching like

1. APC : https://www.php.net/apc/
2. Zend Opcache : https://www.php.net/opcache

There are also few diffferent projects (like XCache, check wiki for PHP accellerators). They can speed up php but you need a root priviliges to install them (they are a PHP modules). If you don't have your own/dedicated server you can forget about it ;(

There is no different way to cache PHP files (in php directly). You can cache only generated html output.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I cleared some roads to handle preload files as I do, although I could see the APC library, is more focused on storage variables. Opcache probably be the most suitable, but has few functions for handling it. I'm testing with this library to see how it goes and then tell you.

Comment: APC is opcode cache + shared user memory. You can use it for both, Zend Opcache is only opchace without storing variables. There is also a trick - APC is available for PHP5.4 and lower. PHP5.5 comes with ZendOpcache as integrated solution, you cannot make APC opcode caching  work with 5.5 because there is no APC version that support PHP 5.5. You can download and install APCU that is APC emulation for shared user memory (variables store)